# How do we deploy azure function in VS Code?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I followed the deployment guide precisely here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs-code?tabs=nodejs#republish-project-files

However, After deploying, In Azure portal, there is no functions in function app.

[image]

And in the output log in VS code:

```
- /Users/myapp/code/test-azure-functions/node_modules/rimraf/dist/cjs/src/bin.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:885:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:730:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/myapp/code/test-azure-functions/node_modules/minipass/dist/cjs/index.js:13:23)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/myapp/code/test-azure-functions/node_modules/minipass/dist/cjs/index.js',
    '/Users/myapp/code/test-azure-functions/node_modules/path-scurry/dist/cjs/index.js',
    '/Users/myapp/code/test-azure-functions/node_modules/glob/dist/cjs/src/glob.js',
    '/Users/myapp/code/test-azure-functions/node_modules/glob/dist/cjs/src/index.js',
    '/Users/myapp/code/test-azure-functions/node_modules/rimraf/dist/cjs/src/index.js',
    '/Users/myapp/code/test-azure-functions/node_modules/rimraf/dist/cjs/src/bin.js'
  ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! test-azure-functions@1.0.0 clean: `rimraf dist`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the test-azure-functions@1.0.0 clean script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I have completely no clue now.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I failed to build before deploying:

I need to run this first:

```
npm run-scripts build
```

Then a `dist` folder will be generated after the build.

Then I can do the deploying steps, and the function would appear.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the given **[MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs-code?tabs=nodejs#republish-project-files)** and I can able to deploy my function to funtion app.

My function runs successfully locally as below,

[image]

In order to use Azure Function Core tools command to deploy the Function like below:-

Open your Vs Code terminal and run the commands below:-

```bash
az login
az account set --subscription "subsription-name"
func azure functionapp publish functionapp-name
```

[image]

[image]

***The function got deployed successfully to the function app at Azure Portal as below,***

[image]

The code runs successfully at Azure Portal also as below,

[image]

Coming to your error code, Some times, there might be corruption in the node_modules directory. To fix this, delete the “node_modules” folder and reinstall all dependencies.

You can try the below command to install node_modules,

```
npm install rimraf --save-dev
```

Below is my package.json file,

**package.json:**

```json
{
  "name": "your-project-name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "func start",
    "test": "echo \"No tests yet...\"",
    "clean": "rimraf dist"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "rimraf": "^5.0.1"
  }
}
```

Run the below commands and try again,

```
npm install
```

Then try to run your code with **fn+f5** and deploy that to function app.